# Error withRef is removed. To access the wrapped instance, use a ref on the connected component when using Redux Form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am trying to get Redux Form to work for the first time and I am getting the following error:

> Invariant Violation withRef is removed. To access the wrapped
>   instance, use a ref on the connected component.

What am I doing wrong? The error is thrown as soon as I write (copy/paste from the example) the store.

Here is the code.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  form: formReducer
})

const store = createStore(rootReducer);


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I have also made a code sandbox that shows the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/07xzolv60

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just update to the latest version of redux-form (8.1.0). There is no need to downgrade.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem, apparently **redux-form** doesn't work well yet with **react-redux** version greater then 6.

For me what helped is downgrading the **react-redux** package to version 5:

```
npm install react-redux@5.1.1 --save
```

Comment: how it this a solution really?

Answer (score 7):

While the above does work, if you'd like to use the latest, all you need to do is refactor your class component to a function component. Look for the `withRef()` API. (Please upvote this as the correct answer to help other devs.)

https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/docs/api/fieldarray.md/#props-you-can-pass-to-code-fieldarray-code-

Comment: Please upvote this answer as the correct answer so that devs don't end up downgrading versions to make it work!

Comment: How do you do that? Could you please edit my fiddle?

Comment: Instead of ```class Something extends React.Component {}```, try ```const Something = (props) => {}```

Comment: @ClaytonRay your last comment is not consistent with your answer. You said `all you need to do is refactor your function component to a class component.` Did you mean refactor from class components to function components?

Comment: I see the confusion. I don't remember this issue but I'm sure I meant refactor from class to function. Either way, you should be able to use either a class or function component, as refs are available in both.

Answer (score 3):

I don't advise downgrading `react-redux` instead I say you update both libraries to their latest versions and problem should be fixed. Kindly refer to Redux Form documentation on migrating from v6 to v8.

https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/MigrationGuide.md

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v6.0.0

The withRef option to connect has been replaced with forwardRef

```
export default 
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps, null, {forwardRef: true})(Component)
```